# Selenium: Quit Python script without closing browser

Tags: python, selenium, sys, keyboardinterrupt

I use the following to handle the situation where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is used to terminate a running Python script.

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "ABORTED"
```

However, this also terminates my `Selenium WebDriver` browser.

Is there a way to terminate the script and keep the browser alive, so that I can continue using it?

What I usually do instead, is to pause the script via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. This unfortunately often causes the browser to freeze and not respond.

Comment: so just don't call driver.quit() right?

Comment: @ChrisHawkes, I think OP doesn't use `driver.quit()`. `sys.exit()` close browser session despite of calling `driver.quit()`

Comment: @Andersson True, although I don't think it matters if `sys.exit()` is in there because Ctrl+C will make everything exit anyway.

Comment: just don't call driver.quit() or sys.exit()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace CTRL+C+`sys.exit()` with `quit()` method to terminate `Python` script without closing browser session. Just use following form:

```
user_choice = raw_input('Please click ENTER button to close application')
if not user_choice:
    print "ABORTED"
    quit()
```

Comment: Why you use `ctrl+C`? Is it mandatory for you to end script this way?

Comment: Well, I guess it's not mandatory to use Ctr+C. If another keypress can be intercepted during the script run, then the problem could be avoided.

Comment: You can close it by pressing `Enter`. Check updated answer