# Can I use xfvbwrapper with selenium to simulate a headless chromium

Tags: python, selenium, chromium, xvfb

On Ubuntu 14.04, I need to start a headless instance of chromium and navigate to a page (no HTML, merely Javascript) that waits messages from a peer (a Websocket server relays the messages). On message reception of a relayed message from the peer, this headless client will run some javascript logic.

So I need this headless chromium to be running all the time my machine is up. I may refresh the page to reset it's state, but this is it.

I was able to [start a headless chromium using Xvfb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754382/how-do-i-start-chromium-browser-in-headless-mode-extension-randr-missing-on-d/757624?noredirect=1#comment1131215_757624), I am just wondering if using this wrapper won't give more flexibility, in case I want to actually script some actions.

I know I know, **Selenium** is meant for automating test suites, but is there a way to use `xvfbwrapper`+`selenium` for bringing up a **headless** client page? how?

My problem is that this will return as soon as the page is loaded ... and then my script ends

```
driver.get("http://somedomain/url")
```

I want my headless chromium to remain up until I decide to kill the script.

I may implement a loop, but I am trying to figure out a smart way that won't peg the CPU.

Comment: Of course it returns, how else can you run other selenium commands? Just because it returns doesn't mean the browser isn't open. In fact, it means the opposite -- if it returns, rather than throwing an exception, the browser is open and ready for you to send it commands.

Comment: Why do you need this javascript to run in a browser? Can't you just run a javascriipt interpreter without xvfb and selenium?

Comment: I realize that. I hope the question doesn't cause frustration. We can't be all that smart or we wouldn't need the StackExchange right? ;) Yes it needs to be in a browser, I need a headless chromium engine.

Comment: So, if it needs to be in a browser, and you know how to open a browser in a headless environment with selenium, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334983/selenium-quit-python-script-without-closing-browser)

```
user_choice = raw_input('Please click ENTER button to close application')
if not user_choice:
    print "ABORTED"
    quit()
```

or

```
 while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```