# How to accept keyboard interrupt without closing Selenium-controled browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I created this `test.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script>
    function inc() {
      var counter = document.test.counter;
      counter.value = parseInt(counter.value) + 1;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="test">
      <p>
        <input type="text" value="0" name="counter" size="5">
        <input type="button" id="increment" value="increment" onclick="inc();">
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and `test.py`

```
import time
from os import path
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get(path.abspath("test.html"))

try:
    n = 5
    for i in range(n):
        print("push %d / %d" % (i + 1, n))
        driver.find_element_by_id("increment").click()
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("interrupted")

print("waiting")
time.sleep(5)
print("bye")
```

in a same directory.

When I run `test.py` from a Command Prompt using a command `python test.py`,
and I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> before `"waiting"` is printed,
the Google Chrome window opened via Selenium is closed.

In my actual code, a loop is invoked from interactive Python console and runs indeterminate times.
I want to fire keyboard interrupts to break from a loop without closing Google Chrome window for investigation and development.

What should I do to archive this?

My environment:

- Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1 (64bit)
- Python 3.5.1 (64bit)
- Selenium 3.141.0
- urllib3 1.24.1
- ChromeDriver 2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387)
- Google Chrome 72.0.3626.119 (Official Build) (64bit)

The system suggested a question [Selenium: Quit Python script without closing browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334983/selenium-quit-python-script-without-closing-browser), but this question didn't seem useful for me because:

- `raw_input()` seems waiting for user input. I want my program run without requiring manual input until I fire keyboard interrupts.
- In my actual code, the time to sleep is long (about 10 minutes) instead of 1 second in the sample. The loop should be broken right after I fire keyboard interrupts, not after the sleeping is done.