# How to interrupt a jupyter kernel without closing Selenium web browser?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook, interrupt

I made a selenium script that fetch data from a page in a loop.

Unfortunately sometimes that loop goes stuck: that is, the loop iterates over without fetching the data I need, for example because the webpage serves a new type of data, or because the format of the data is not the one I expected.

I thus need to interrupt the cell that contains the loop, that is to stop the loop, but without closing the Selenium web browser, so that I can fix the loop and restart it.

But the problem is, if I press "Interrupt kernel", the Selenium web browser is closed automatically.

How can I prevent the Selenium web browser to be closed when I press "Interrupt kernel"?

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55003956/how-to-accept-keyboard-interrupt-without-closing-selenium-controled-browser).